Make the week start on Sunday instead of Monday in Angular @worktile/gantt (ngx-gantt)
I need to make the Gantt to start on Sunday instead of Monday - we are using Angular @worktile/gantt (ngx-gantt) - Right now the Gantt's UI shows that the week starts on Monday.
This is what I tried and didn't work:
viewOptions: any = {
    dateFormat: {
      yearMonth: 'MM/y',
      yearQuarter: 'y',
      year: 'y',
      week: 'w',
      month: 'MM',
    },
    dateOptions: {
      weekStartsOn: 6,
    },
  };

<ngx-gantt
  #gantt
  [groups]="groups"
  [items]="items"
  [viewOptions]="viewOptions"
  [loading]="isLoading"
  [draggable]="true"
  [viewType]="ganttDateMap[dateView]"
  (barClick)="onBarClick($event)"
  (dragEnded)="onBarDragEnded($event)"
>



I have managed to solve this problem by creating custom component that extends GanttView then edited the viewStartOf function as below
viewStartOf(date: GanttDate) {
    return date.startOfWeek({ weekStartsOn: 6 });
  }

You can also find more details in their github example
https://github.com/worktile/ngx-gantt/tree/master/example/src/app/gantt-custom-view
